# ArcGIS: Generate Random polygons within a polygon

Tags: arcgis-9.3

I have a generic polygon layer, would it be difficult to do subdivide the polygon into sub polygons provided they're all relative of the same area? Let's say divide a polygon into 10 or so sub polygons.

Comment: There won't be a unique solution.  To understand any solution, you need to know three things: (1) which subpolygons can possibly arise through this procedure; (2) the *probabilities* with which they are chosen; and (3) the probabilities with which *groups* of them are chosen (that is, statistical dependencies in selection).  Random generation of anything is usually done to simulate something, so look to this for clues to answering (1) - (3).  In particular, **what are you simulating?**

Comment: I'm trying to model urban development in undeveloped areas with no streets. So let's say you have an area of 100 acres, divide it into 10 - 10acre sub areas. and each area will have a subdivision a small store, etc ...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

Randomly drop points into the polygon's minimum bounding rectangle until 10 of the points fall within the polygon.  Create a voronoi diagram of the 10 points then intersect it with the original polygon.

Comment: This elegant simple procedure works for convex polygons but can fail for concave ones (unless you allow for multi-part subpolygons).  Also, it seems the solutions will tend to consist of relatively large interior polygons bordered by smaller ones.  I wonder whether this is consistent with whatever "relative of the same area" means.